Determine the latest version of a package from the OpenSuse build service
I want to automate the binary download of a package served from the openSUSE build service - for example this one: https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Ajustkidding&package=ueberzugpp.
If one navigates to Ubuntu 22.04, then Grab binary packages directly they're given a list of debian package download links which can be passed to programs like curl / wget. However these links contain the version of the package, so I would have to know that beforehand to be able to download the latest ueberzugpp package at any given time.
Does the openSUSE build service offer a way / API endpoint to help determine the latest version of a package at any given time?
P.S. I know I can add this repository as a PPA but currently this is not an option I'm considering.

if the project is published, the binaries will appear on download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/username/repository
The repository data within that directory can be parsed with the relevant tooling. For libzypp repos, there are python bindings in createrepo_c. Also zypper itself can provide output in XML format.
For Debian packages similar tools exist.

What would be the link for the example URL that I posted ? I tried https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/justkidding/ueberzugpp but I get 404.
I'm asking primarily for the debian package so  I cannot usecreaterepo_c or zypper.
